# Baire Category theorem - Determining First or Second Category

Tags: functional-analysis, baire-category

I don't have a mathematician background (I am an engineer). I understand some concepts but the Baire Category theorem and the ideas of first and second category are still very abstract for me.

I have to show the following:

> **1.** Of what category is the set of all rational numbers:
>
> **a.** in $\mathbb{R}$?
>
> **b.** in itself (taken with the usual metric)?
>
> **2.** Of what category is the set of all integers:
>
> **a.** in $\mathbb{R}$?
>
> **b.** in itself (taken with the metric induced from $\mathbb{R}$)?

In both of the problems (b), **why does the metric affect the problem?**

Thanks for your time!

Comment: By "of what cathegory ", do you mean "open or closed"?

Comment: He means first category or second category in the sense of Baire.

Answer (score 4):

A set is of first category if it can be written as a countable union of sets whose closure has empty interior. (A set whose closure has empty interior is commonly called *nowhere dense*, but I won't use this term in the remainder of this answer.) Otherwise it is of second category. If you aren't already familiar, the closure of a set $A$ is the smallest closed set which contains $A$; the interior of $A$ is the largest open set which is contained in $A$. If you're not familiar with, for instance, how you can think of $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ vs. $\mathbb{Z}$ as a subset of itself with the topology inherited from $\mathbb{R}$, I would suggest you look up the term "subspace topology".

Let's look at the part about the integers. Purely in set theory (no topology here), we can write $\mathbb{Z} = \bigcup_{n=-\infty}^\infty \{ n \}$, which is a countable union.

In the topology of $\mathbb{R}$, the closure of $\{ n \}$ is $\{ n \}$ and the interior of $\{ n \}$ is $\emptyset$ (because $\{ n \}$ does not contain any intervals). So we've shown that $\mathbb{Z}$ is of first category as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

In the topology of $\mathbb{Z}$, the closure of $\{ n \}$ is still $\{ n \}$. However, in the topology of $\mathbb{Z}$, sets with only one element are actually open as well as closed. You can see this because $\{ n \}=\{ m \in \mathbb{Z} : |m-n|<1/2 \}$, which is the intersection of an open interval with $\mathbb{Z}$. This means that the interior of $\{ n \}$ is $\{ n \}$. That is, we have written $\mathbb{Z}$ as a countable union of sets, but the closures of these sets do not have empty interior. The Baire category theorem says that in fact you *cannot* write $\mathbb{Z}$ as a countable union of sets whose closure has empty interior, because $\mathbb{Z}$ is a complete metric space.

The situation is different for $\mathbb{Q}$, which is *not* a complete metric space (its completion is $\mathbb{R}$). As a result the answer to 1b turns out to be different than the answer to 2b.

Comment: Hi Ian! Can you explain me about the set $Q$? For me its clear that $Q$ is meager in $R$ but I'm not sure if it meager in itself. Thanks!

Comment: @CletoPereira In $\mathbb{Q}$ you have that the interior of the closure of each singleton is empty, so because $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable it is of first category in itself.

Comment: Thaks. I got the idea but it is very confused for me! I tried to repeat the idea that you used and concluded that $\{q_i\}=\{q \in \mathbb{Q}: |q-q_i| <\varepsilon \}$ isn't an open interval in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @CletoPereira In $\mathbb{Z}$, the closure of $\{ x \}$ is $\{ x \}$ and the interior of $\{ x \}$ is $\{ x \}$, so singletons are not nowhere dense. In $\mathbb{Q}$, the closure of $\{ x \}$ is $x$ but the interior of $\{ x \}$ is $\emptyset$, so singletons are nowhere dense. Thus writing $\mathbb{Z}$ as a countable union of its singletons doesn't tell you that it is first category in itself, and in fact it is not, as you should expect from the Baire Category Theorem. Writing $\mathbb{Q}$ as a countable union of its singletons does tell you that it is first category in itself.